# Child Aura Component not Loading for Some Users

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, security

Strange situation. This code works perfectly for me, but does not load for some users. I have searched permissions and security on Aura bundles, but cannot find what I need.

Here is the code. The idea is that the contactDetails component should be able to find the correct information if it is given a contact ID. The oppContact component is what loads the record and give the child component the contact ID.

When a regular user opens the lightning page, the top part of the page is greyed out and has a spinner that doesn't go away. Also, when I run the console debugger, I don't get the `contactDetails component is running...........................` like I expect.

One thing it might be is the GID field?? That is not editable by everyone. Is that causing some kind of issue?

What do?

---

contactDetails

```
<aura:component access="global">
<aura:attribute name="contactID" type="Id" access="global"/>
<aura:attribute name="contactRecord" type="Object"/>
<aura:attribute name="simpleContRecord" type="Object"/>
<aura:attribute name="recordError" type="String"/>

<!-- Load Contact -->
<force:recordData aura:id="contactRecordData"
                  recordId="{!v.contactID}"
                  targetRecord="{!v.contactRecord}"
                  targetFields="{!v.simpleContRecord}"
                  targetError="{!v.recordError}"
                  recordUpdated="{!c.contLoaded}"
                  layoutType="FULL"
                  mode="EDIT"/>

<aura:attribute name="loaded" type="Boolean" default="false"/>
<aura:attribute name="editable" type="Boolean" default="false"/>

<!-- Display a lightning card with details about the record -->
<div class="Contact Details">
    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.loaded}">
        <!--show details of the contact -->
        <lightning:card iconName="action:add_contact" title="{!v.simpleContRecord.FirstName + ' ' + v.simpleContRecord.LastName}">
            <aura:if isTrue="{!v.editable}">
                <!-- Edit the record if the edit button is pressed -->
                <div class="slds-p-left_medium">
                    <lightning:recordForm recordId="{!v.contactID}" 
                                          objectApiName="Contact"
                                          layoutType="Compact"
                                          columns="2"
                                          mode="edit">
                    </lightning:recordForm>
                </div>

                <aura:set attribute="else">
                    <!-- Display contact as read only by default -->
                    <lightning:recordViewForm recordId="{!v.contactID}" objectApiName="Contact">
                        <div class="slds-p-horizontal--small">
                            <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters">
                                <!-- First Column -->
                                <div class="slds-col">
                                    <p class="slds-text-heading--small slds-p-top_x-small">                                    
                                        <lightning:outputField fieldName="GID__c" />
                                    </p>
                                    <p class="slds-text-heading--small slds-p-top_x-small">
                                        <lightning:outputField fieldName="Primary_Email__c" />
                                        <!--<lightning:formattedEmail label="example email" value="{!v.simpleContRecord.Primary_Email__c}"/>-->
                                    </p>
                                    <p class="slds-text-body--small slds-text-color_weak slds-p-top_x-small">
                                        Phone<br/>
                                        <lightning:clickToDial class="slds-text-body_regular" value="{!v.simpleContRecord.Phone}" recordId="{!v.contactID}"/>
                                    </p>
                                    <p class="slds-text-heading--small slds-p-top_x-small">
                                        <lightning:outputField fieldName="Invalid_Phone__c" />
                                    </p>
                                    <p class="slds-text-heading--small slds-p-top_x-small">
                                        <lightning:outputField fieldName="SMS_Opt_In__c" />
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                                <!-- Second Column -->
                                <div class="slds-col">
                                    <p class="slds-text-heading--small slds-p-top_x-small">
                                        <lightning:outputField fieldName="Timezone__c" />
                                    </p>
                                    <p class="slds-text-heading--small slds-p-top_x-small">
                                        <lightning:outputField fieldName="hed__AlternateEmail__c" />
                                        <!--<lightning:formattedEmail label="example email" value="{!v.simpleContRecord.Primary_Email__c}"/>-->
                                    </p>
                                    <p class="slds-text-body--small slds-text-color_weak slds-p-top_x-small">
                                        Alternate Phone <br/>
                                        <lightning:clickToDial class="slds-text-body_regular" value="{!v.simpleContRecord.Alternate_Phone__c}" recordId="{!v.contactID}"/>
                                    </p>
                                    <p class="slds-text-heading--small slds-p-top_x-small">
                                        <lightning:outputField fieldName="DoNotCall" />
                                    </p>
                                    <p class="slds-text-heading--small slds-p-top_x-small">
                                        <lightning:outputField fieldName="Most_Recent_Activity_Date__c" />
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>      

                        <!-- Button to allow editing -->
                        <br/>
                        <div class="slds-var-p-around_small button-background">
                            <button class="slds-button slds-button_neutral" title="Edit Contact" onclick="{!c.editContact}">Edit Contact</button>
                        </div>
                    </lightning:recordViewForm>
                </aura:set>
            </aura:if>                
        </lightning:card>

        <!-- show spinner if it is loading -->
        <aura:set attribute="else">
            <lightning:spinner alternativeText="Loading the Contact" />
        </aura:set>
    </aura:if>
</div>

<!-- Display Lightning Data Service errors, if any -->
<aura:if isTrue="{!not(empty(v.recordError))}">
    <div class="recordError">
        {!v.recordError}</div>
</aura:if>
```

contactDetailsController.js

```
({
contLoaded : function(component, event, helper) {
    var changeType = event.getParams().changeType;
    if (changeType === "ERROR") { 
        /* handle error; do this first! */ 
        console.log('Error loading');
        console.log('Event Paramaters: ' + event.getParams());
    }
    else if (changeType === "LOADED") { 
        console.log('contactDetails component is running...........................');
        console.log('Contact loaded successfully');
        component.set("v.loaded",true);
    }
    else if (changeType === "REMOVED") { /* handle record removal */ }
    else if (changeType === "CHANGED") {
        console.log('Contact was updated');
        component.set("v.editable",false);
        component.set("v.loaded",true);
    }
},

editContact : function(component, event, helper) {
    console.log('Allowing Contact to be edited');
    component.set("v.editable",true);
}
```

})

---

Here is the parent, oppContact:

```
<aura:attribute name="oppRecord" type="Object"/>
<aura:attribute name="simpleOppRecord" type="Object"/>
<aura:attribute name="recordError" type="String"/>
<aura:attribute name="contactID" type="Id"/>

<!-- Load Opp -->
<force:recordData aura:id="oppRecordRD"
                  recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                  targetFields="{!v.simpleOppRecord}"
                  targetError="{!v.recordError}"
                  recordUpdated="{!c.oppLoaded}"
                  layoutType="FULL"
                  mode="VIEW"/>

<aura:attribute name="opploaded" type="Boolean" default="false"/>

<!-- Display a lightning card with details about the record -->
<div class="Contact Component">
        <aura:if isTrue="{!v.opploaded}">
            <!--show Contact component -->
            <c:contactDetails contactID="{!v.contactID}"/>

            <!-- show spinner if it is loading -->
            <aura:set attribute="else">
                <lightning:spinner alternativeText="Loading the Contact" />
            </aura:set>
        </aura:if>
</div>

<!-- Display Lightning Data Service errors, if any -->
<aura:if isTrue="{!not(empty(v.recordError))}">
    <div class="recordError">
        {!v.recordError}</div>
</aura:if>
```

oppContactController.js

```
({
oppLoaded : function(component, event, helper) {
    var changeType = event.getParams().changeType;
    if (changeType === "ERROR") { 
        /* handle error; do this first! */ 
        console.log('Error loading');
        console.log('Event Paramaters: ' + event.getParams());
    }
    else if (changeType === "LOADED") {
        console.log('oppContact component is running.......');
        component.set("v.contactID", component.get("v.simpleOppRecord.Contact__c"));
        console.log('oppContact component loaded the opp correctly');
        component.set("v.opploaded",true);
    }
    else if (changeType === "REMOVED") { /* handle record removal */ }
    else if (changeType === "CHANGED") { 
        console.log('Opportunity was updated');
        component.set("v.opploaded",true);
    }
}
```

})

Comment: Can you check the FLS for users who are not able to see the component?

Comment: I did that, and the users should have what they need. I will post the solution I found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. It was surprising, but it seems I did not have the direct reference Contact__c on the page layout for that profile. My best guess is that when I used forceRecordData the `layoutType="FULL"` will only pull the fields from the page layout. Since the Contact__c field was not on there, it was not able to pass that ID on to the child.